# Manipulating a query so that null values are not shown in a full outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, full-outer-join

How would you manipulate a query so that the rows with null values in a table resulting from a full outer join do not show up in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE value IS NOT NULL

You can find a full explanation here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Comment: Not Sure if this answers my question because I don't think this applies to full outer joins

Comment: Make sure your WHERE filter is after your ON selection.

Comment: There is [no such thing as "Postgre"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). And you should link to the [current version of the manual](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual). Please fix your answer, and [look into formatting aids while being at it.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Yea, sorry. On my phone from the road. Maybe someday I'll be a pro at stackoverflow...